# Why changing an element's width affects its sibling?

Tags: html, css, width

It's not the first time it happens and I have never found a good explanation.

In this particular case, I have an `h3` and a `p` inside a `div`. As soon as I changed the `p`'s `width`, the `h3`'s width changed as well, like as the width was being applied to their parent.

1. Why does this happen?

and

2. I found that the fix (or at least one of the fixes) in my case, was to apply `display: inline-block` to the `h3`. If you remove it, you'll see that the button takes the paragraph's width of `95vw`. How come does this work?

Thank you

```js
let button = document.querySelector('.button')
let body = document.querySelector('.body')
let container = document.querySelector('.container')

button.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
  let colorOne = parseInt((Math.random() * 255) + 1)
  let colorTwo = parseInt((Math.random() * 255) + 1)
  let colorThree = parseInt((Math.random() * 255) + 1)

  let colorOneOne = parseInt((Math.random() * 255) + 1)
  let colorTwoTwo = parseInt((Math.random() * 255) + 1)
  let colorThreeThree = parseInt((Math.random() * 255) + 1)

  let deg = parseInt((Math.random() * 360) + 1)

  body.style.background = 'linear-gradient(' + deg + 'deg' + ', ' + 'rgb(' + colorOne + ', ' + colorTwo + ', ' + colorThree + ')' +  ',' + 'rgb(' + colorOneOne + ',' + colorTwoTwo + ',' + colorThreeThree + '))'
  //linear-gradient(45deg, rgb(28,28,84), rgb(38,58,119))

  document.querySelector('.color').innerText = 'linear-gradient(' + deg + 'deg' + ', ' + 'rgb(' + colorOne + ', ' + colorTwo + ', ' + colorThree + ')' +  ',' + 'rgb(' + colorOneOne + ',' + colorTwoTwo + ',' + colorThreeThree + '))'

  button.style.border = 'none'
  document.querySelector('.scrollto').style.display = 'block'
})

window.addEventListener('touchmove', ()=> {
  body.style.background = 'white'
  document.querySelector('.color').innerText = ''
  document.querySelector('.scrollto').style.display = 'none'
  button.style.border = '1px solid black'
})
```

```css
.button {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  border-radius: .5em;
  padding: .3em .7em;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  position: relative;
  background: white;
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 382px) {
  .button {
    width: 10em;
  }
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

.color {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px black;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  display: block;
  width: 95vw;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.container {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40vh;
  left: 50vw;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.scrollto {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 50vw;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: .7em;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body class="body">
  
    <div class="container">
      <h3 class="button">Generate Gradient</h3>
      <p class="color"></p>
    </div>
  
    <div class="line">
      <p class="scrollto">swipe on screen to reset</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: I see no problem with this code. (using firefox) even changed the width of the paragraphs!?

Comment: no, there's no problem. it is if you remove the display on inline-block from the ".button". I wanted to understand the why of such behaviour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove the `inline-block` from `h3` it will get its default display which is `block` and this means *take full width of the parent element*.

Now, the trick is the width of the parent element that is a `position:absolute` one. Its width is defined by the shrink-to-fit algorithm which means that the width is based on its content.

The content is a `h3` block element and a `p` block element. You defined only the width of `p` so this will define the width of the `position:absolute` element and then the h3 will be full width of its parent element so it will logically follow the width set to `p`.

Here an illustration of different cases to better understand:

```css
.container {
  position:absolute;
  border:1px solid;
}
.container > * {
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h3 class="button">Generate Gradient</h3>
  <p class="color">some text </p>
</div>

<div class="container" style="top:150px">
  <h3 class="button">Generate Gradient</h3>
  <p class="color">a text longer than the above one</p>
</div>

<div class="container" style="left:250px">
  <h3 class="button" style="display:inline-block">Generate Gradient</h3>
  <p class="color">a text longer than the above one</p>
</div>
```

You can see that by default both should be 100% of the parent width and the longer content will define that width. If you make one element `inline-block` it will simply fit its content and will no more obey to the block elements rule which is to be 100% width of the parent.

---

This is a simplified explanation, if you want more accurate detail you need to refer to the specification and find how the width is calculated in each case.

Block elements: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#blockwidth

Inline block elements: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#inlineblock-width

Absolutely positioned elements: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-width